# Mac OS X echo $(date) in .bash_profile gives stale date

Tags: shell, date, alias, bash

In terminal, if i run `echo $(date)`, it will give me the current date.

However, when i put the command in **.bash_profile** as an alias

```
alias dt="echo $(date)"
```

it will give me stale date. Namely, when i run `dt`, it will always give me the same date.

Any workaround? Thanks!

Comment: Expansion comes sooner than you expect!

Comment: Why overcomplicate this? Just do an alias dt=date

Comment: i need to use that $(date) info to do some extra work. like generating the current time as a file name: $(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S").png. But for the simplicity of asking a question on stackoverflow i just use $(date).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to quote it to prevent expansion:

```
alias dt="echo \$(date)"
alias dt="echo \"\$(date)\""  ## (internally quoted)
```

Or just use a single quote:

```
alias dt='echo $(date)'
alias dt='echo "$(date)"'  ## (internally quoted)
```

And better yet use a function:

```
dt() { echo "$(date)"; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer! It would be great if you could explain the answer alias dt="echo \$(date)". What is that backslash do and why it works? Thanks!

Comment: @JohnnySun What we actually want to do is have a literal assignment of `echo $(date)` to the alias. If we don't quote `$(date)`, it would expand and the assignment would instead be like `echo Sun 22 Sep 20:46:35`, making it a constant value everytime you run dt. It's the same with using the single quote version. Expansion doesn't happen in single quotes.